# sql select with conditional field replacement

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

I'm using postgres.  I have a single table inheritance 'listings' table.  Listings can have many variations and belong to a parent through parent_id.  Both parent and child have a 'title' field.  Occasionally, and unfortunately, the variation title is null, and we need to keep it that way because it reflects how the original data was imported, so doing a data migration to populate variation.title with it's parent's title is not an option.

But when we display the data in our web view, we always want to show a title.

I would like to query against all the listings (parents and variation) for a merchant, and if the title is null for the child, then replace the null with the parent's title.  Right now I'm doing this in ruby on rails, which can be slow as it has to loop through each ruby object.  Is there a way to do this in SQL?

We are doing something like this now:

```
listings = Listing
                .includes(:parent)
                .where(:merchant_id => current_merchant.id)
                .where(product_id: params[:ids])
                .select(:type, :id, :sku, :product_id, :title, :quantity, :price,   :channel_id, :status, :state, :parent_id)

#fix blank titles
listings.each do |l|
  next if l.title
  l.title = l.parent.title if l.parent_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. Based on this [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html)

```
listings = Listing
            .includes(:parent)
            .where(:merchant_id => current_merchant.id)
            .where(product_id: params[:ids])
            .select('type, COALESCE(listings.title, parents.title), ...)
```

I think it will work if `listings.title` is `NULL`. If it can be blank string you can use `CASE` statement.

PS maybe you should use `LEFT JOIN` for table parents instead of including it.

Comment: LEFT INNER JOIN? :) [That's a new one?](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)